# Why are images blurry in Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

Internet Explorer 8 is scaling up all bitmap images on webpages, making them blurred.

I have my machine's DPI settings at "Smaller - 100% (default).

Any idea why this is happening, and whether there is a fix?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Check if your "zoom" setting is set to something other than "100%.":** <kbd>Alt</kbd> - <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>

The fix: set the "zoom" setting to 100%!

Comment: Ah cool. I tried ctrl+/- but couldnt seem to find a setting where images looked sharp, and I didnt realise that the zoom level was persistent. Gotta love that 'secret menu bar' feature of IE.